# Print the result of the REST API GET call

Tags: php, rest, file-get-contents

I am performing `REST API GET` call using `PHP`. Is there any easy way to browse `$result` and save its content to arrays.

```
    <?php

        $url = '...';

        try 
        {
            $result = file_get_contents( $url );
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        var_dump($result);
    ?>
```

Here is an output (just some first lines):

> string(7272)
>   "{"request":{"airport":{"requestedCode":"BCN","fsCode":"BCN"},"date":{"year":"2013","month":"7","day":"10","interpreted":"2013-07-10"},"hourOfDay":{"requested":"0","interpreted":0},"numHours":{"requested":"6","interpreted":6}

Comment: Please add an example of response data. $result = file_get_contents( $url ); echo '<pre>'; var_dump($result);

Comment: @JimL: Please see my updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php

    $url = '...';

    try 
    {
        $result = file_get_contents( $url );
        $obj = json_decode($result);
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($obj);
?>
```

OR

```
<?php

    $url = '...';

    try 
    {
        $result = file_get_contents( $url );
        $array = json_decode($result, true);
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The var_dump returns a lot of data, but I'm interested only in specific object ["flightStatuses"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
... I tried var_dump($obj["flightStatuses"]);, but it does not work. How to read the specific object?

Comment: If you decode it to an object you have to refer to the values as you should in an object. $obj->flightStatuses